# Properties of a weighted maximal function $\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{[m(B_r(x))]^\alpha}\int_{B_r(x)} f(y) dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, harmonic-analysis

Where can I find a reference on the properties of the following "weighted Hardy-Littlewood maximal function"?

> $$Mf(x) = \sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{[m(B_r(x))]^\alpha}\int_{B_r(x)} f(y) dy, $$
>   where $m(B_r(x))$ is the Lebesgue's measure of the ball of radius $r$ and centre $x$ and $\alpha > 0$.

In particular, I'll be interested

- in $L^p$ estimates of $Mf$,
- in the relationship between $Mf(x)$ and Holder continuity of $f$,
- and in the relationship between $Mf(x)$
  and $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{[m(B_r(x))]^\alpha}\int_{B_r(x)} f(y) dy$$

Comment: I wouldn't call this a weighted H-L maximal function because the measure in the integral doesn't have a weight. I would call this a fractional H-L maximal function. This has been studied; see, for instance, "Regularity of the Fractional Maximal Function" by Kinnunen and Saksman.

Comment: @Ryan Thank you for the reference. I'd like the $\alpha$ that appears in your paper as $0 \le \alpha < n$ to be negative though.

Comment: In the paper, the alpha is in the numerator, whereas yours is in the denominator.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, and I want it in the denominator with positive exponent.

Comment: Ah, I see! I apologize.

Comment: @Dal, The last limit in your question seems to make sense only if $\alpha =1$. This is because we can write $$
\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{ m(B_r(x))^\alpha } \int_{B_r(x)} f(y) dy = 
\lim_{r \to 0}  m(B_r(x))^{1-\alpha} \frac{1 }{ m(B_r(x)) } \int_{B_r(x)} f(y) dy.
$$
Now if $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$, then the averaged integral converges to $f(x)$,
and hence the limit in question is either 0 if $1-\alpha>0$ or is infinity (if $f(x) \neq 0$) when $1-\alpha<0$.  And for integrable $f$, almost all points are Lebesgue points.   Am I missing something ?